# DSolve can not solve my PDE

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

I'm having some trouble using `DSolve` to solve a partial differential equation.

This is my code:

```
pde = d*cp*D[T[t, z], t] == k*D[T[t, z], {z, 2}] + Q;

sol = 
  DSolve[
    {pde, T[0, z] == Tamb, (D[T[t, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 0, 
     (-k*D[T[t, z], z] /. z -> a) == h*(T[t, a] - Tamb)}, 
    T[t, z], {t, z}]
```

The output is the differential equation, but it's not evaluated

I'm assuming that there is a mistake in what I wrote because even when I use `DSolve` with the partial differential equation that is given as example in the `DSolve` article in the Documentation Center, I don't get a solution.

For example, I dont get a solution from this code either:

```
pd = D[y[x, t] t] + 2 D[y[, t], x] == 0;

sol1 = DSolve[{pd, y[0, t] == Sin[t]}, y[x, t], {x, t}]
```

I am using Wolfram Mathematica 7.0.

Comment: There are several things. First, version 7 had no `DSolve` functionality applied for PDE, as much as I remember. Second, I tried your code in Mma 11.3 and it still returns it unevaluated. This means, that Mma "does not know" the answer. A minor note: this: `\a` is incorrect. Put simply `a`.

Comment: Thank you so much, so i can only use NDsolve then to solve a partial differential equation? or there is any other function that you know of?
I ask you this because i would prefer to obtain not a numerical solutions

Comment: There's a missing `x` in the partial derivative of `y` with respect to `x` (in the second example).  Fix it, and it works in V11.3: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xPxT6.png -- Like @Alexei, I'm not sure this will work in V7. You can look in the V7 documentation to see if there are PDE examples for `DSolve`. You can also try [Wolfram Development Platform](http://www.wolfram.com/development-platform/) for free.

Comment: `Maple 2018.2` can solve first example analytically.

Comment: Mariusz how do you solve it analitically? i just tried in the Wolfram Development Platform but it didnt work

Comment: `Maple` is another alternative `CAS` software. https://maplesoft.com

Answer (score 2):

Using `Mathematica 12.2.0` now can solve.

First example:

```
pde = d*cp*D[T[t, z], t] == k*D[T[t, z], {z, 2}] + Q;

sol = DSolve[{pde, T[0, z] == Tamb, (D[T[t, z], z] /. z -> 0) == 
0, (-k*D[T[t, z], z] /. z -> a) == h*(T[t, a] - Tamb)}, 
T[t, z], {t, z}]

(*{
 {T[t, z] -> Piecewise[{{Tamb + Inactive[Sum][(2*(1 - E^(-((k*t*K[2, K 
[1]])/(cp*d))))*h^2*Q*Cos[z*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]]*
      Sin[a*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]])/(k^3*K[2, K[1]]^(3/2)*Sqrt[-((h*(-((a*h)/k) - 
 Sin[a*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]]^2))/k)]*
      Sqrt[(h*(a*h + k*Sin[a*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]]^2))/k^2]), {K[1], 1, Infinity}], 
 h/(k*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]) == Tan[a*Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]] && 
   cp*d*k > 0 && h*k > 0 && Element[K[1], Integers] && K[1] >= 1 && K[2, K[1]] > 0}}, 
 Indeterminate]}}*)
```

Second example:

```
pd = D[y[x, t] t] + 2 D[y[x, t], x] == 0;

sol1 = DSolve[{pd, y[0, t] == Sin[t]}, y[x, t], {x, t}]

(*{{y[x, t] -> E^(-((t x)/2)) Sin[t]}}*)
```

Comment: Oh finally I see an example illustrating the "more capable ODE and PDE solvers" (quoted from `guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn122`)! But then another question comes up: Is there an elegant way to solve the equation `h/(k Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]) == Tan[a Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]]`?

Comment: @xzczd .With this question you will probably have to report it to `WRI`.I can't help.

Comment: I believe it's not yet ready, or Stephen won't mention nothing about this in his blog. :)

Comment: @xzczd. `Maple 2020.1` gave me the quite similar answer. The `equation` can be only solved numerically.

Comment: I retract my words "I believe it's not yet ready", when `h`, `k`, `a` are numeric and proper interval is specified, `Solve` can handle it since _v8_: `{h = 1, k = 1, a = 1}; sol = 
 Solve[{h/(k Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]) == Tan[a Sqrt[K[2, K[1]]]], 0 <= K[2, K[1]] <= 10000}, 
  K[2, K[1]]]; sol // N`

Answer (score 0):

I tried it using the LaplaceTransform, but I haven't get the final analytical answer. These are my codes:

```
pde = d*cp*D[T[t, z], t] == k*D[T[t, z], {z, 2}] + Q;
ic = T[0, z] == Tamb;
bc1 = D[T[t, z], z] == 0(*z\[Rule]0*);
bc2 = -k*D[T[t, z], z] == h*(T[t, z] - Tamb)(*z->a*);
solbc1 = DSolve[{bc1}, T, {t, z}][[1]]
solc1 = DSolve[{pde /. solbc1, ic /. solbc1}, C[1][t], t][[1, 1]]     (*C[1][t] -> (Q t + cp d Tamb)/(cp d)*)
bc1new = T[t, 0] == (Q t + cp d Tamb)/(cp d);
solbc2 = DSolve[{bc2}, T, {t, z}][[1]]
solc1 = DSolve[{pde /. solbc2, ic /. solbc2}, C[1][t], t][[1, 1]]
T[t, z] /. solbc2[[1]] /. solc1 /. z -> a
bc2new = T[t, a] == ((-1 + E^((h^2 t)/(cp d k))) k Q)/h^2 + Tamb;
teqn = Simplify[
LaplaceTransform[{pde, bc1new, bc2new}, t, s] /. 
HoldPattern[LaplaceTransform[a_, t, s]] :> a]
tsolmid = FullSimplify[DSolve[teqn, T[t, z], z]][[1, 1, -1]]
```

The InverseLaplaceTransform seems difficult to get the results for this question...

Comment: and I hope someone can teach me how to solve it~

Comment: Indeed, `LaplaceTransform` is a possible choice for solving the problem symbolically, but your method for handling the 2 b.c.s are unnecessary and, more importantly, improper. By solving e.g. `DSolve[{pde /. solbc1, ic /. solbc1}, C[1][t], t][[1, 1]]`, you're essentially assuming the i.c. and b.c. are consistent, but in many cases this is not true, and the problem solved here is exactly one of them. (`T[0, z] == Tamb` and `(-k*D[T[t, z], z] /. z -> a) == h*(T[t, a] - Tamb)` conflicts at $(t,z)=(0,a)$. ) The standard way is to transform the PDE and b.c. directly with e.g. `LaplaceTransform`.

Answer (score 0):

Anohter method：

```
    pde=d*cp*D[T[t,z],t]==k*D[T[t,z],{z,2}]+Q;
    ic=T[0,z]==Tamb;
    bc1=D[T[t,z],z]==0(*z0*);
    bc2=-k*D[T[t,z],z]==h*(T[t,z]-Tamb)(*za*);
    solbc1=DSolve[{bc1},T,{t,z}][[1]];
    solc1=DSolve[{pde/.solbc1,ic/.solbc1},C[1][t],t][[1,1]];     (*C[1][t](Q t+cp d Tamb)/(cp d)*)
    bc1new=T[t,0]==(Q t+cp d Tamb)/(cp d)
    solbc2=DSolve[{bc2},T,{t,z}][[1]];
    solc1=DSolve[{pde/.solbc2,ic/.solbc2},C[1][t],t][[1,1]] ;           (*C[1][t](^((h z)/k) (-1+^((h^2 t)/(cp d k))) k Q)/h^2*)
    T[t,z]/.solbc2[[1]]/.solc1/.z->a;
    bc2new=T[t,a]==((-1+E^((h^2 t)/(cp d k))) k Q)/h^2+Tamb

    (*First let’s deal with the complex boundary condition*)
     T[t_,z_]=c[t,z]+(t Q)/(d*cp);
    Simplify[pde]
    eqnx[z_]=d*cp*D[c[(k*t)/(d*cp*z^2)],t]-k*D[c[(k*t)/(d*cp*z^2)],{z,2}](*x=(k t)/(cp d z^2)*);
    eqn'=FullSimplify[eqnx[Sqrt[(k t)/(d*cp*x)]]]==0
    solx=DSolve[eqn',c[x],{x}][[1,1]]/.x->(k*t)/(d*cp*z^2);(*c[(k t)/(cp d z^2)]C[2]-2 Sqrt[π] C[1] Erf[1/(2 Sqrt[(k t)/(cp d z^2)])]*)
    T[t_,z_]=C[2]-2 Sqrt[π] C[1] Erf[1/(2 Sqrt[(k t)/(cp d z^2)])]+(t Q)/(d*cp);
    solc2=Solve[Limit[T[t,z],z->0]==(Q t+cp d Tamb)/(cp d),C[2]][[1,1]]  (*use bc1new*)
    T[t_,z_]=T[t,z]/.solc2;
    solc1=Solve[Limit[T[t,z],z->a]==((-1+E^((h^2 t)/(cp d k))) k Q)/h^2+Tamb,C[1]][[1,1]] (*use bc2new*)
    T[t_,z_]=Simplify[T[t,z]/.solc1]
```

Well, actually I don't know if my result is right.I hope so ^_^

Comment: Hi, it does not seem that the result satisfies the `pde`.  Also, a little syntax issue: You might want to consider `FullForm[eqn']` and whether that's what you meant to do.

Comment: @ Michael E2 ，Thanks for your reminding , I missed the existence of 'Q'，so the transform didn't satisfy the equation any more.I have corrected the mistake

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is incorrect, just compare with the numeric solution, it's totally different. One critical mistake I can spot is the line `eqnx[z_]=d*cp*D[c[(k*t)/(d*cp*z^2)],t]-k*D[c[(k*t)/(d*cp*z^2)],{z,2}](*x=(k t)/(cp d z^2)*);`, if I understand it correct, you're utilizing the method for obtaining similarity solution, right? That method only works for problem defined on infinite or semi-infinite domain AFAIK, because in a finite domain (like the $[0,a]$ in this problem) the required symmetry is broken.